# self made encryptor/decryptor not working as expected with key more than 3 characters

Tags: java, encryption

This event is triggered when I click the convert button on the encryptor. It switches things around and displays the result.

```
private void jButton21ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    text = jTextField8.getText();
    key = jTextField7.getText();
    result = "";
    //loop for all items in text
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
        c = (int) text.charAt(i);
        //loop for all items in key
        for (int a=0; a<key.length(); a++) {
            //adding ascii of each key value to ascii of text character 
            c += (int) key.charAt(a);
            //adding I to make sure all letters dont appear the same
            c += i;
            //make sure ascii's stay between target values (excluding null)
            while (c > 126) {
                c -= 125;
            }
        }
        //converting ascii back to char and adding to result
        result += (char) c;
    }
    //displaying result in text box below
    jTextField6.setText(result);

}
```

This is what is triggered in the decryptor when convert is pressed. It does what the encryptor does backwards (at least i think..)

```
private void jButton22ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    text = jTextField11.getText();
    key = jTextField10.getText();
    result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
        c = (int) text.charAt(i);
        for (int a=0; a<key.length(); a++) {
            c -= (int) key.charAt(a);
            c -= i;
            while (c < 1) {
                c += 125;
            }
        }
        result += (char) c;
    }
    jTextField9.setText(result);
}
```

However when i use a longer key, the decryptor no longer works.

## Encryption 1

- input:   aaa
- key:     aa
- output:  )+-

## Decryption 1

- input:   )+-
- key:     aa
- output:  aaa

Working as planned and expected

## Encryption 2

- input:   aaa
- key:     aaa
- output:  "   "(3 spaces)

The encryption just returned 3 spaces. This shouldn't happen in the first place as I add 'i' making them different. It should have given 3 different letters/symbols.

## Decryption 2

- input:"   "(3 spaces
- key:  aaa
- output:tqn

The decryption of 3 spaces with aaa as key returned something different.
I have checked the code many times and cannot find what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You should extract the encryption/decryption stuff into a separate class - that will enable you to test your algorithm in isolation without having to deal with the GUI bits at the same time...

Comment: screenshots are irrelevant to this question, as it's not about the GUI, please remove the images, and add only the relevant texts (input, output, expected output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter such a problem, you should:

- extract the code relevant to your problem and remove the unnecessary stuff
- test the input/output programmatically

See below what it could look like. Once you have done that, you will realise that your code works as expected but the second encrypted string contains a line return which you probably can't easily copy paste. You should restrict your range to printable characters (32 - 126).

The output of the program is:

> ok: aaa (key=aa) => )+- => aaa
>   ok: aaa (key=aaa) => 
>    => aaa

You can see that the second run has a line return in it.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  test("aaa", "aa");
  test("aaa", "aaa");
}

private static void test(String input, String key) {
  String encrypted = encrypt(input, key);
  String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
  if (decrypted.equals(input)) {
    System.out.print("ok: ");
  } else {
    System.out.print("error: ");
  }
  System.out.println(input + " (key=" + key + ") => " + encrypted + " => " + decrypted);
}

public static String encrypt(String input, String key) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    int c = (int) input.charAt(i);
    //loop for all items in key
    for (int a = 0; a < key.length(); a++) {
      //adding ascii of each key value to ascii of text character
      c += (int) key.charAt(a);
      //adding I to make sure all letters dont appear the same
      c += i;
      //make sure ascii's stay between target values (excluding null)
      while (c > 126) {
        c -= 125;
      }
    }
    //converting ascii back to char and adding to result
    result += (char) c;
  }
  return result;
}

public static String decrypt(String input, String key) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    int c = (int) input.charAt(i);
    for (int a = 0; a < key.length(); a++) {
      c -= (int) key.charAt(a);
      c -= i;
      while (c < 1) {
        c += 125;
      }
    }
    result += (char) c;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are converting to ASCII values below 32, which are not what you want. The GUI front end renders them as spaces, and that in turn gives the wrong output of your decrypt.

[image: ASCII table]

Set your encryption checker to

```
while (c > 126) {
    c -= 93; // was -125
}
```

And your decryption to

```
while (c < 1) {
    c += 93;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, displaying non ascii characters is highly output system dependant. Your second encryption test does **not** end in three spaces but in 3 non printable characters of respective codes 13 (CR or '\r'), 14 and 15.

Your output system - the GUI - does not know how to display them and does not output anything, what **you** wrongly see as 3 white spaces.

Conclusion : you encryption system is not guaranteed to output a printable string and cannot be used directly. You should at least encode the output value in base64 to be sure it is printable.